# Need advice replacing a whirlpool Jacuzzi bathtub button

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

The air button on my Whirlpool Jacuzzi bathtub went out on me. My daughter really wants it fixed so she can play in the tub but I'm not very familiar with these. Is the button interchangeable, or do I need to find an exact replacement? The part# is C841000.

The tub is over 18 years old and I'm having problems finding an exact match that isn't ridiculously overpriced for what it is. I'm very frugal and don't want to spend money on parts that won't work, but don't want the self-frustration of attempting to repair it myself and failing.

Thanks for your time!

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

That particular button is proprietary and will be very difficult to find.

However the button may not be the problem. It may be the switch.  The button just pumps air through a tube to an electric switch that is activated/ deactivated when you push the button.

You will need to get to the switch and check the electrical connections.
First thing would be to check to see if the breaker providing power is not open.

If you do not have tools such as a noncontact tester or voltmeter or are unfamiliar or uncomfortable with checking electric, your best bet is calling an electrician.

Comment: I should have clarified, the button isn't technically "broken". It can be turned on, but takes several attempts to get it to turn off. I will check the switch and see if it may need some cleaning. Thank you for your input.